# Rocket.Chat as Docker-Container using sub folder

Tags: url, docker, file-upload, rocket.chat

I'm trying to run RocketChat as a docker container with reverse proxy in a sub folder (https://001docker2t/rocketchat).
My problem is that file upload is using the wrong url (https://001docker2t/ufs/...) and stay at 0%.

As in the documentation for sub folders (https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/running-in-a-sub-folder) i set the ROOT_URL to https://001docker2t/rocketchat/. In the application i set under Admin > General only the domain.

***Do i have a wrong configuration or is there something wrong with uploads using subfolders?***

***Docker calls:***

docker run --name rocketchatdb --restart unless-stopped -d -v /var/docker/rocketchat/db:/data/db mongo:3.0 --smallfiles

docker run --name rocketchat --restart unless-stopped -p 172.17.0.1:3000:3000 --link rocketchatdb --env ROOT_URL=https://001docker2t/rocketchat/ --env MONGO_URL=mongodb://rocketchatdb:27017/meteor -d rocket.chat

***Versions:***

NODE_VERSION    4.8.2

YARN_VERSION    0.22.0

RC_VERSION  0.54.2

Answer (score 0):

Update to [latest version](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/docker-containers/available-images) (verified on 0.59.3), it was fixed already.